# Narrow Eloquent Polymorphic Relationship by Type

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I'm working on adding a "favorites" feature to my application where a `User` can mark multiple `Household` or `Strategy` records as *favorites*. Following the tutorial [here](https://dev.to/bdelespierre/how-to-implement-a-simple-like-system-with-laravel-lfe), and also by dissecting the existing [`overtrue/laravel-favorite`](https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-favorite) package, I've got a working setup which defines a `morphTo()` relationship of `Favorite` to `Household` / `Strategy`, a `belongsTo()` relationship from `Favorite` to `User`, and a `hasMany()` relationship from `User` to `Favorite`.

However, I'm curious to know if its possible to narrow the relationship from `User` to `Household` and `Strategy` such that I can write `User::first()->favorite_households`, and get an Eloquent `Relation` back rather than an Eloquent `Collection`.

If I extend the logic from the [`overtrue/laravel-favorite`](https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-favorite) package, I wind up with something like this:

```php
public function favorite_households()
{
    return Household::whereHas(
        'favorites',
        fn ($q)  => $q->where('user_id', $this->id)
    );
}
```

It works, insofar as I get the data I'm seeking, but without retuning a relationship, I'm limited with respect to that upon which I can build further. Is this the best-possible outcome, or should I completely rethink the way I'm going about this?

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You are finishing your method with `->get()` that will return 100% of the times a `collection`... you need to use a `belongsTo` or `belongsToMany` or any similar related to `relationships`...

Comment: I think as long as you remove the `get()` method, you can still add queries. After you add your queries, call the `get()` function after the last query.

Comment: @felixbmmm @matiaslauriti , thank you for your input! I actually dropped `get()` right before I posted my question, and then forgot to update the post. At this stage, from a semantic point of view, I guess I'm sort of bemused with regard to what the best practice would be for this arrangement. Should `households` be a scope on the relationship `favorites` underneath `User`, or should `favorites` be a scope under relationship `households` on `User`? I can facilitate both, but I'm not sure which ultimately makes the most sense. My apologies for the erratic nature of the question.

Comment: I would do inside User model: `favourites`, inside Favorite model: `household` and `strategy`. If you do it this way, you can be more flexible on what you want to achieve, for ex., if you want to get only household favorites, I believe you can do `$user->favourites()->where('type', 'household')->household`. You could also separate the `favorites` relationship on User model to become `favoriteHouseholds` and `favoriteStrategies`, but keep in mind that you always have to call `household` and `strategy` relationship inside Favorite model to get the object.

Comment: @felixbmmm , thank you for the explanation! I took my eyes off of the problem for a day and came to the realization that my problems were largely with my own perspective. What I didn't mention was that the relationship of `User` to `Household` is of type `hasManyThrough()`. In the end, I should have started with `Household::visibleToUser($user)->favoritesOfUser($user)`, defaulting `$user` to `auth()->user()` — lifting that into another scope later on. However, I did learn quite a bit about about polymorphism through your reply. Thank you, again! I'll post some of my findings for others to see.